# Flutter Firebase Database variable not receiving value after method

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a method where the information is read from the Firebase (Cloud Firestore), but the values are not being assigned to the variables when invoked, can someone help?

There is testt variable just to test that the Method is being called and is running, but I cannot understand why the other variables don't get any value.

```
class _VehicleDetailsState extends State<VehicleDetails> {
  String speed, place, testt;

  void displayData() {
    testt = "Test";
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Cars')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: Routes.idCar)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((result) {
        place = result.data()['place'];
        speed = result.data()['speed'];
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    displayData();
    print(testt);
    print(place);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'Vehicle Details',
          style:
              new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(Routes.routeName);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firestore is *asynchronous*, meaning you can ask it for information, and it'll go get that information in the background, while your code keeps working. This is why your values haven't changed; because Firestore doesn't have them by the time the rest of your code executes.

You can combat this in two ways. Using the `await` keyword, or the `.then()` method. Guess what, you already use the `.then()` method in your firestore call! You tell it to go get the data AND THEN execute whatever code you put in the `.then()` callback.
`

```
   //Ran right away
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cars').where('id', isEqualTo :Routes.idCar).get().then((value){
     //Ran only once data has been retrieved from firestore (which usually takes a few milliseconds)
     value.docs.forEach((result) {
     place = result.data()['place'];
     speed = result.data()['speed'];
     });});`
```

The other way you can get the data is using the `await` keyword. The await keyword says "wait for this asynchronous function to give me a value, and then continue with the rest of the code". However, in order to use the await keyword, the function it's in needs to be asynchronous as well. If you think about it, that makes sense, because you don't want your entire code locking up over one web request. What if it fails? Then your entire app is frozen! Here's an example using the same sort of code from before.

```
Future<void> displayData() async {
testt = "test";
   // Waits for firestore to give back the value, then executes the rest of the code.
   dynamic value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cars').where('id', isEqualTo :Routes.idCar).get();
  // The below code only starts once the above code has a value.
     value.docs.forEach((result) {
     place = result.data()['place'];
     speed = result.data()['speed'];
     });
```

You may notice the `Future<void>` where just `void` used to be. This is a Future, it's what most asynchronous things in flutter are based on. You can use await and then on it.

In the case of your code, I'm sorry, but you're probably going to have to restructure a bit to account for loading data. Your build method cannot be asynchronous, but you can make the proper changes to the UI from your `displayData()` method.

**TL;DR:
It's null because it doesn't have the value yet.**

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed and explanatory answer, I realized my mistake